# Convergence of integral/series

Tags: calculus, integration

If I have the following expression:

> $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3}$

Can I then deduce that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges, because right hand side does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...yes, of course! What you wrote says the integral equals ***a number*** , so yes: this means the integral converges.

Comment: Thank you! But isn't there a difference between the statement "the sum converges to a number" and "the sum is a number"?

Comment: Oops Sorry. I see :) I'm just a little confused.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to say, for example, for a finite $C$

$$\int^{\infty}_{0}f(x)\, dx=C < \infty \implies \int^{\infty}_{0}f(x)\, dx < \infty$$

Thus

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^3}=\zeta(3)$$

So the integral converges!  You even know what the integral converges to.